# Unable to connect to WiFi with a Wemos S2 Mini clone?

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

I bought [this Wemos S2 Mini three-pack](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B0B291LZ99) from Amazon last week and I've been pulling my hair out trying to get them to connect to WiFi. I have the Ardiuno IDE `1.8.19` set to a LOLIN S2 Mini from Espressif `2.0.3` [as directed](https://www.wemos.cc/en/latest/tutorials/s2/get_started_with_arduino_s2.html), with Arduino WiFi `1.2.7`, and am running this code:

```c
#include <WiFi.h>

void setup() {
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin("ssid", "psk");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address:");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  //
}
```

All I get is endless `........` in the Serial Monitor. I've tried:

- running [the esp32 WiFi Scan samples](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/examples/WiFiScan/WiFiScan.ino) and all I get is "no networks found"
- attempting to rename my router's ssid to something without a space
- connecting to my phone's hotspot
- flashing all three boards
- choosing other random ESP32-S2 dev boards in the Boards Manager
- several different USB-C to USB-C and USB-C to USB-A cables into my computer

No dice. Bad hardware? What am I missing?

Comment: ESP32 only supports 2.4 GHz wifi, so double-check that your AP-s are not 5 GHz.

Comment: Good thought! There are several 2.4GHz access points around my house, mine included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purchased an actual LOLIN S2 Mini from [AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3256802958877264.html), ran the same code, worked immediately. Don't buy these shitty knockoffs from Amazon.

Comment: Mine were exactly the same appearance, only without the trademark (wemos.cc) under the version number (V1.0.0). And of course, they don't work, so caution here!

Answer (score 1):

Add Capacitor 1-10uF between EN and 3.3V
It helps me

Answer (score 0):

1. enable "Verbose" in Arduino for compilation - you will get all the
   messages/errors to start with
2. make sure your AP does not have white/black list for MAC addresses
3. ssid/password ok? (sorry, but sometimes it happens)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did enable verbosity (thanks for telling me about that, that's good to know!), but nothing helped. Turns out, it was just bad hardware from Amazon knockoffs.

Answer (score 0):

i confirm that many of these lolin clone boards have problem with wifi connection...after buying 5pcs of these devices from aliexpress....(and a friend 3pcs from same supplier)..
all have the same problem.....already tried to reload updated firmware..but nothing...still remains a card that can be used like any arduino..but WITHOUT POSSIBILITY TO CONNECT TO WIFI NETWORK !!!!

Answer (score 0):

After install tasmota and reset S2 mini, it's in ap mode (you will find a wifi network on the phone or PC with the name tasmota-xxxxxx-yyyy;
I associate you with it preferably from the PC and the browser will automatically open at 192.168.4.1 where you can set wifi now)

AFTER SET WIFI:

Tasmota
Successful WiFi Connection

Redirecting to new device's IP address

192.168........
Tasmota 13.1.0 by Theo Arends

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).